# Mysql syntax error for left join query

Tags: mysql

I keep getting a syntax error with this query. I'm trying to work out the count of rows where:

1) the column earnings_campaign_free_id = 43

2) the column earnings_campaign_paid_id = 43

So two outputs: paid_views, free_views

```
SELECT 

cp.campaign_paid AS paid_views
cf.campaign_free AS free_views

FROM

(
    SELECT COUNT(earning_paid_campaign_id) AS campaign_paid
    FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_paid_campaign_id = 43
) cp

LEFT JOIN

(
    SELECT COUNT(earning_free_campaign_id) AS campaign_free
    FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_free_campaign_id = 43
) cf

ON cf.earning_campaign_free_id = cp.earning_paid_campaign_id
```

This is the error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'cf.campaign_free AS free_views
>
> FROM
>
> (
>       SELECT COUNT(earning_paid_campaign_i' at line 4

How do I fix this error?

Comment: you muss a `,` after `AS paid_views`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT 

cp.campaign_paid AS paid_views,
cf.campaign_free AS free_views

FROM

(
    SELECT earning_paid_campaign_id,COUNT(earning_paid_campaign_id) AS campaign_paid
    FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_paid_campaign_id = 43
) cp

LEFT JOIN

(
    SELECT earning_campaign_free_id,COUNT(earning_free_campaign_id) AS campaign_free
    FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_free_campaign_id = 43
) cf

ON cf.earning_campaign_free_id = cp.earning_paid_campaign_id
```

You are trying to join basis of `ON cf.earning_campaign_free_id = cp.earning_paid_campaign_id` but when you write `sub query` then `mysql` create `temporary` table and you are not select that id. so error occur

Comment: You are also missing the comma. Will give the error :)

Comment: @rohit 
i corrected it thank you,  my query is correct  :)

Comment: @AmyNeville:- Its good to go to the errors and check the cause ;)

Comment: @AmyNeville other then commas there are also a error you are not selecting ids which basis you join two subquery